# Unknown variable or field "generateData"

Tags: android

Let me start by saying this is my first post on here and I am very new to android development. My question is this.  The generateData is giving me an error saying unknown variable or field. I did my best to try declaring it but cannot find a way to do it after much searching. Here is my code.

```
import android.os.*;
import android.support.v4.app.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.app.Fragment;
import com.mycompany.myapp.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class ExpenseFragment extends Fragment
{

    public ExpenseFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentexpense, container,false);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), ***generateData***);

            ListView listView = (ListView) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return myInflatedView;}

    private ArrayList<Item> generateData(){
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        items.add(new Item("Item 1","First Item on the list"));
        items.add(new Item("Item 2","Second Item on the list"));
        items.add(new Item("Item 3","Third Item on the list"));

        return items;
    }}`
```

I have several other XML and java files if they are needed. Just let me know. Go easy on me and correct anything you think needs fixing. Still learning how things work. Thank you very much for your assistance

Comment: I'm not a Java expert so bear my ignorance, but did you try replacing `generateData` with `generateData()`? You declared a method but you're calling it like it's an instance variable...

Comment: Thanks to you both. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parenthesis when calling the method.

`MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), generateData());`

Answer (score 0):

Modify you code like this :

```
public class ExpenseFragment extends Fragment
{
    ArrayList<Item> listIntems;
    public ExpenseFragment() {
      //call generate data
        listIntems= generateData();
      }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentexpense, container,false);
// Pass data structure in this. 
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), listIntems);

            ListView listView = (ListView) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return myInflatedView;}

    private ArrayList<Item> generateData(){
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        items.add(new Item("Item 1","First Item on the list"));
        items.add(new Item("Item 2","Second Item on the list"));
        items.add(new Item("Item 3","Third Item on the list"));

        return items;
    }}`
```